Google Analytics & Google Adsense in NextJS
I want to add Google Analytics and Google Adsense to my website in NextJS. I found this official doc: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/third-party-libraries#google-tag-manager
According to this, its enough to add:
 <GoogleTagManager gtmId="GTM-XYZ" />

However, I have problem with understanding how Google adsense works. I know that google adsense require from me to include another script to my head (my account is not approved yet for google ads). The problem is that I want to let user decide whether he accepts analytics and advertisement cookies. I was going to simply remove GoogleTagManager from my head for analytics but what with advertsiement? I.e. I can't remove the Google Ads script because I dont want to remove ads at all so have can I distinguish between "personalized adverts" (user accepted cookies) and "not personalized" adverts? How should I construct my code to handle all cases?
